# Do not understand Perl hash construct in a histogram code with respect to an array

Tags: perl, hash, histogram

I was looking at this histogram perl code: http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/62-how-to-generate-a-histogram-with-perl and I do not understand what line#3 is dong:

```
# This calculates the frequencies for all available bins in the data set   
my %histogram;     
$histogram{ceil(($_ + 1) / $bin_width) -1}++ for @list;
```

Questions I have are:

1. What is `$_` here? I tried to print it but it turns empty.
2. I do understand the math but what does the `++` hash and `for @list` mean? I have not seen this construct before.

Comment: `perldoc -v $variable` will check the `perlvar` documentation for a specific punctuation variable. (Be sure to use appropriate quoting/escaping for your shell.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$_` is the current element of `@list`
2. The code can be rewritten as follows:

   ```
   # Enumerate all values in the input list
   foreach my $value (@list) {
       # Compute histogram bin into which to place the current value
       my $bin_index = ceil(($value + 1) / $bin_width) - 1;

       # Increment the number of values in the bin
       $histogram{$bin_index}++;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It is a postfix `for` loop.

Your attempt to print `$_` is probably failing because you are putting it outside the loop (but you didn't share your code for that attempt).

It could be rewritten as:

```
my %histogram;
for my $value (@list) {
    $histogram{ceil(($value + 1) / $bin_width) -1}++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_` here is used as implicit foreach variable; same thing could be explicitly written as

```
my %histogram;
for my $n (@list) {

  my $key = ceil(($n + 1) / $bin_width) -1;
  $histogram{$key} += 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_` is the current context value. In this case, the current iteration element of your `for @list` loop.

The hash contains the number of occurrences for each "bin".

The bin is calculated using the `ceil` function and a `$bin_width`, and it serves as the key for the hash (the value is the occurrence counter that gets accumulated into).

The `++` increments the current count for this bin in every iteration. On the first time this happens, Perl automatically assumes `0` for the missing element and the `++` will set it to `1`.